# Rewrite query URL from adwords

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for a way to rewrite the querystring from adwords in IIS. The reason is my site reports and error a potential dangerous requiest with the `&` sign.

I'm getting this:

```
&gclid=CjwKCAjw8uLcBRACEiwAaL6MSWvHvgjch-b2BAqbjz1PRKQQuoP9wsDpAqcbceGihRWdetXUxmwF2BoC5EsQAvD_BwE
```

And I want to rewrite it to

```
?gclid=CjwKCAjw8uLcBRACEiwAaL6MSWvHvgjch-b2BAqbjz1PRKQQuoP9wsDpAqcbceGihRWdetXUxmwF2BoC5EsQAvD_BwE
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Where does it come from? Because a `&` is valid in a url as long as it is not the first delmititer of a querystring after the domain. Correct: `www.google.nl?id=5&gclid=xxx`. Incorrect `www.google.nl&gclid=xxx`

Comment: The problem is the & sign comes as the first character after the url to my site. like this www.google.nl&gclid=xxx and it need to be www.google.nl?gclid=xxx for my site to accept it